# External Data source through apex custom adapter

Tags: callout, lightning-connect, apex-webservice, salesforce-connect, externalobjects

I want to connect the external database from salesforce. I have developed the custom adapter (DataSource.Connection class and DataSource.Provider class).

In connection class, Sync method is working and I have created 4 external object using Sync method. But I am facing issue in structuring the query, search etc others methods and how to make callouts?

I have already referred this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_start.htm  but didnt get proper solution.

Can anyone share the sample code to make callouts?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

These examples were the most helpful for me (examples of SF Connect custom adapters for various web services including GitHub, Google Drive, and so on):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connector_examples.htm?search_text=github

When the platform calls the DataSource.Connection class's `query` method, the parameter passed in is the class `DataSource.QueryContext`. This gives you all of the information of the query context in which you are trying to load external object records (documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_QueryContext.htm#apex_DataSource_QueryContext_queryMoreToken).

Specifically, the `DataSource.QueryContext` attribute `tableSelection`, of type `DataSource.TableSelection`, contains all of the information you need to structure your callouts (documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_TableSelection.htm#apex_class_DataSource_TableSelection).

The `DataSource.TableSelection` class has the properties:

**columnsSelected**

- List of columns to query. Corresponds to the SELECT clause in a SOQL or SOSL query.

**filter**

- Identifies the query filter, which can be a compound filter that has a list of subfilters. The filter corresponds to the WHERE clause in a SOQL or SOSL query.

**order**

- Identifies the order for sorting the query results. Corresponds to the ORDER BY clause in a SOQL or SOSL query.

**tableSelected**

- Name of the table to query. Corresponds to the FROM clause in a SOQL or SOSL query.

---

If we take a simple example, where we have some external object `Sample__x` that we're trying to load, given its indirect lookup to an Account in the external system:

```
SELECT ExternalId, Account__c, Some_Property__c FROM Sample__x WHERE Account__c = '1234'
```

Then:

- **columnsSelected**: [{columnName=ExternalId, ...},  {columnName=Account__c, ...}, {columnName=Some_Property__c, ...}]
- **filter**: {columnName=Account, columnValue='1234', ...}
- **tableSelected**: 'Sample__x'

---

I suggest looking through the documentation in the `DataSource` namespace, there is quite a good deal of other possibilities and useful classes beyond what the simple example above gives you, including search and query pagination.